# Nowhere dense sets in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

A set $A$ in a metric spaces $(E, d)$ is nowhere dense if $(\overline{A})^c$ is dense, i.e, if $\,\,\,\overline{(\overline{A})^c}=E$.

Let $(a_n)$ a sequence of points of $E$ that converges to $a\in E$.

Is the set $A=(a_n)$ nowhere dense??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily: what if $E=A\cup\{a\}$, and the points of $A$ are all distinct? For example, take $$E=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$ and $a_n=\frac1n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Then $A$ is actually a dense open subset of $E$.

Comment: Brian  $A$ is open?

Comment: @Roiner: $A=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ is indeed open in $E$: it consists entirely of isolated points.